# How to compile PJSIP lib for IOS and test it for XCODE with sample IPJSUA

Tags: ios, xcode, sip, pjsip

I've following the instructions on the official trac of PJSIP for compile the library for iOS, but nothing to do the project doesn't want compile ! I've restart the instructions 6 times and it doesn't work.

I'm on xcode 5.1.1, iOS simulator on 7.1

My error are multiple:

```
library not found for -lavfilter
library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9
```

And i don't know how to resolve this error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved.
But I've an other problem,
The project compile, he run on my iphone, but I've just a windows on my phone who it's write telnet to 192....:2323

I go on my terminal and i telnet to 192... 2323
And after I try do make a call with call new sip:nameOfAnOtherCli@domainOfMyAsteriskServer

Comment: so how u solved this? "library not found for -lavfilter" from main question